# File update followed by file upload in Selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium, file

I have a scenario where first I update an excel column with certain values using one test case (test case 1) and then use that file for upload in the next test case (test case 2). I am able to successfully update the file and also able to browse the file for upload. the problem is that the content is not being read from the file. I just have to open the excel file created and perform the save action manually and then when I run the test (test case 2)related to uploading it works perfectly fine. I am not sure what is causing the issue. it would be of great help if someone can support this issue.

Here are the test steps

1. Update file column values - code snippet

   ```
   public void setColValues(String fileName, String sheetName, int colIndex, List<Integer> sData) {
        try {
            String excelPath = System.getProperty("director to file path");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excelPath);
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sh = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);

            int rowCount = sh.getLastRowNum();
            logger.info(rowCount);
            int index = 0;
            for (int rowCounter = 2; rowCounter <= rowCount; rowCounter++) {
                sh.getRow(rowCounter).getCell(colIndex).setCellValue(sData.get(index));
                index++;
            }
            fis.close();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(excelPath), false);
            workbook.write(fos);
            workbook.close();
            fos.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
   ```
2. go to a specific URL
3. Click the browse button and pass the file path
4. Click the button to upload

Comment: Hi Abbie. Can you post your code where you are selecting the file with selenium and where you are reading the file content? Providing more details would probably help you get helpful answer/s.

Comment: Hi Mo, I am actually not reading the file it is just a simple selenium command to browse the file and click a button to upload. the only pre requisite for my test is that I write to file some values and then use that file in selenium to upload it. I have the query updated

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are not passing a `File` instance to `FileInputStream` constructor?

You wrote:

```java
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excelPath);
```

Try instead:

```java
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelPath));
```

Comment: Thank you Mo. I updated the code and still it is not working. I assume there is something wrong with the format I am not sure either. It is a guess because when I open the excel file manually and just click save and try to use that file for the upload it works